# How to handle jumping back to previous screens in iOS

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller

I am just looking for a sanity check here.

I have a screen that the user passes through on the way into the main application.  That screen can be navigated back to from almost anywhere in the system.

As it stands I am just presenting ViewControllers without using a NavController to manage them (it does not seem applicable for most of my app, since screens are not necessarily sequential or related to one another).

My question is, if I have presented VC1, then navigate to other screens, and finally want to present VC1 again, I am doing something like:

```
[self presentViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC1"] animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Is this bad form?  Am I leaking memory by creating a bunch of VC1 instances or is there some magic that uses the previously created one?

If it is bad form, how do I get back to the original VC1 to reuse it?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you pegged it: It's not a great idea to have multiple instances of the same view controller in memory at the same time. Every time you instantiate a new view controller and present it modally, you'll consume more memory.

The most elegant solution is the iOS 6 unwind segue. But most of us would be unwilling to give up on iOS 5 support quite yet.

If you need to support iOS 5, you could contemplate using navigation controller, but hide the navigation bar if you don't like it in your user interface. Then replace modal segues with push segues and now you can do `popToRootViewController` whenever you want to return to the main view controller.

Comment: Oh boy!, i totally miss understood the question. I'm going to delete my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Rob.  One issue I have with the popToRootVC idea is that there are times when the user might jump back to VC1 and then decide it was not what he wanted to do and want to return to where he was.  Currently this is handled by a toggle button that brings up VC1 and dismisses it on the subsequent press.  If I popToRoot, I will lose that, right?

Comment: Since VC1 is a sort of home-base, what if I attached it to the AppDelegate, and just presented the single instance from there?

Comment: If you use `popToRootViewController` or unwind segues, you can't "cancel" to get back. A more complicated solution to your problem would be to use view controller containment, but I'm not sure you'd want to go there. Or you could use a tab bar controller if your UI lends itself to that.

Comment: Ok, thanks Rob.  One last question for you... VC1 has 4 directions it can go (via buttons), all of them invoke performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:  Are the presented VCs from those methods accumulating too, or is there some reuse going on under the covers?

Comment: Basically, yes. Technically it depends upon the nature of the segue, but if it's a push or modal segue, you'll be consuming more memory.